# How can I inject context when testing components?

Tags: reactjs, testing, components, jestjs, enzyme

The issue I'm facing is that when I inject the context, my test is seeing the default context I set in `MahContext`. I've tried using Shallow, I've tried it without the `context` wrapper around the values and it doesn't matter. Shallow gives me an empty object, which is odd. I've also tried adding `childContextTypes: { mahContext: PropTypes.object }` to the second parameter in `mount` and `shallow` to no avail.

My Context (with default):

```
const MahContext= React.createContext({ id: 0, name: '' })
```

My Provider:

```
const MahProvider = props => (
    <MahContext.Provider value={props.value}>
        {props.children}
    </MahContext.Provider>
)
```

The component tree (in app.js):

```
<MahProvider value=({9, "Johnny Utah"})>
    <ParentOfMahComponent />
</MahProvider>
```

My component to test:

```
class MahComponent extends Component {
    ...
    async componentDidMount() {
        // for my test, results in 0 and '', the defaults
        // which causes my test to fail as there is a validity check 
        // following
        const { id, name } = this.context
    }
}

MahComponent.contextType = MahContext
```

My test:

```
const component = mount(
    <MahComponent />, 
    {
        context: {
            id: 7,
            name: "John Wick"
        }
    }
}
```

Comment: Which react version are you using? Looks like enzyme doesn't support the new context yet.

Comment: I'm using 16.7.

Comment: @10101010 you may be right...